# HttpClient - DNS changes are NOT honoured

Tags: c#, testing, dotnet-httpclient

I've read a few articles and the pitfalls of using a static HttpClient and the solution. One of the articles being - http://byterot.blogspot.ca/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html

I've implemented the solution and want to test to ensure that what the article proposed will actually work.

The following is the code that we are trying to avoid:

```
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new ApiHandler()))
            {
                var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://test.com/api/Tiers");
                var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }).ContinueWith(async task =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new ApiHandler()))
            {
                var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://test.com/api/Tiers");
                var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }).ContinueWith(async task =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new ApiHandler()))
            {
                var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://test.com/api/Tiers");
                var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        });
```

When I view the traffic in fiddler:

[image]

The behavior is as expect. Each create and dispose forces a connection to be established when the the request and response are completed.

The proper and proposed way to use the HttpClient is to for it to be static:

```
    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient(new ApiHandler());
    static void Main()
    {
        ServicePointManager
            .FindServicePoint(new Uri("https://test.com"))
            .ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 1000; // 1 second
        ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 1000; // 1 second

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var httpResponse = await HttpClient.GetAsync("https://test.com/api/Tiers");
            var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }).ContinueWith(async task =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000); // delay 5 seconds
            var httpResponse = await HttpClient.GetAsync("https://test.com/api/Tiers");
            var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }).ContinueWith(async task =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000); // delay 10 seconds
            var httpResponse = await HttpClient.GetAsync("https://test.com/api/Tiers");
            var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I'd expect the same behavior as the previous image however it looks like the following:

[image]

And if I then add `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;` I get the desired outcome however this is what we want to avoid - for each request response to create a connection.

So is my desired outcome in Fiddler correct? or am I missing something with setting the `ConnectionLeaseTimeout` and/or `DnsRefreshTimeout`? I'd really like to test this behavior and ensure that setting those properties on `ServicePointManager` resolves the know DNS issue with a static instance of HttpClient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddler registers itself as a proxy. By default it listens on 127.0.0.1, port 8888. So to get correct service point object for your case you have to do this:

```
ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(
    new Uri("https://test.com"), 
    new WebProxy(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8888")))
.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 1000; // 1 second
```

Now you will see correct outcome. Note that it will be not exactly as you expect. First request will open new connection. Second request will *not* open new connection, even though 5 seconds has passed. Instead, it will set `Connection: close` header on request, indicating that connection should be closed. Then, next request (third) will finally initiate new connection. This is expected behavior as far as I can tell for `ConnectionLeaseTimeout`.